# Phonegap - get local JSON data (array)

Tags: json, cordova, getjson

I'm having difficulty getting some JSON data that locally stored in my phone using `$.getJSON`. My json data have following structure (**allData.json**):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Steve",
        "address": "Some address",
        "keyword": "test"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bill",
        "address": "Another address",
        "keyword": "cast"
    },
    ...
]
```

To perform getting procedure in **JS** I'm using:

```
$.getJSON("allData.json", function(json) {
    if (json != '' || json != undefined) {
        var myData = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(myData);
    } else {alert("json is undefined/ empty");}
});
```

**Error:** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Link to the [FILE](http://db.tt/5tD8xS7C)

Comment: Can you post the exact JSON you used? (Or using chrome inspector, see what data the browser received)

Comment: @Nirk please have look to `UPDATE` section.